# Require class with pure Ruby

Tags: ruby, require

I'm with the following problem:

I'd like to require a 'config/application.rb' file to my *index.rb*.

In my task, I have to use pure Ruby.

config/application

```
Dir["app/models/*.rb"].each do |file|
  require_relative file
end

Dir["app/importers/*.rb"].each do |file|
  require_relative file
end
```

index.rb

```
require 'config/application'

contas_endereco = ARGV[0].to_s
transacoes_endereco = ARGV[1].to_s

conta_arquivo = Arquivo.new(contas_endereco)
transacoes_arquivo = Arquivo.new(transacoes_endereco)

transacoes_importer = TransacoesImporter.new(conta_arquivo, transacoes_arquivo)
transacoes_importer.importar
```

But I got this error:

```
/home/kelvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- config/application (LoadError)
    from /home/kelvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from index.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I tried to use require_relative too, but I got the following error:

```
/home/kelvin/workspace-ruby/desafio-dinda/config/application.rb:2:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/kelvin/workspace-ruby/desafio-dinda/config/app/models/transacao.rb (LoadError)
    from /home/kelvin/workspace-ruby/desafio-dinda/config/application.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/kelvin/workspace-ruby/desafio-dinda/config/application.rb:1:in `each'
    from /home/kelvin/workspace-ruby/desafio-dinda/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from index.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from index.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try `require './config/application'`

Answer (score 4):

> require 'config/application'

In Ruby, files included with [Kernel#require](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require) must generally be in the *$LOAD_PATH* or given as relative paths, and don't include the filename extension. Some examples include:

- Add the script's directory to your $LOAD_PATH.

  ```
  $:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
  require 'config/application'
  ```
- Require a file relative to the current working directory.

  ```
  require './config/application'
  ```

You might also use [Kernel#load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load) with an absolute path. For example:

```
load '/path/to/config/application.rb'
```

Comment: For clarity it's best to use `$LOAD_PATH` instead of the mysterious `$:`, a symbol very difficult to search for on Google.

Comment: @tadman Agreed, but I put them both in the answer because folks are likely to see both in the wild. :) Thanks for the comment! Fighting for readability over cleverness is always a good idea.

Comment: Note that `require`ing a file relative to the current working directory is at the least *very* brittle and potentially *very* dangerous, since the current working directory is outside of your control. That's the reason why `.` isn't part of the default search path on Unix for several decades, and has been removed from `$LOAD_PATH` in 1.9. *Always* use `require_relative` which is relative to the current *file*, which *is* under your control.